# How can I change the values of a numpy array stored in a TensorFlow Variable Without Changing ANY other properties of the Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to change the weights of one layer of a neural net to a new set of known values. The current set of values is:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
...
>>> curr_layer.weights
<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4, 1, 64) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ 0.02059445, -0.01320859, -0.00185177, ...,  0.02550568,
          -0.02180868,  0.00089696]], 
         ...

        [[-0.03411875, -0.00027762, -0.00894349, ...,  0.04085622,
           0.02792494, -0.02052956]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

For the sake of this example, I created a zero array with the same shape:

```
>>> silly = np.zeros([4,4,1,64])
```

However, when I use `assign` to transfer the values, the name of the graph node associated with the Tensor also changes:

```
>>> curr_layer.weights[0].assign(silly)
curr_layer.weights[0].assign(silly)
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(4, 4, 1, 64) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],
       ....
       [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Where now `'conv2d/kernel:0'` has become`'Unread Variable`'. How do I prevent this from happening? How do I change *only* the values associated with the tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name doesn't actually change:

```
a = tf.Variable(np.zeros((3, 4)), name='test')
a.name
```

prints `test:0`. And then

```
a.assign(np.zeros((3, 4)))
a.name
```

still prints `test:0`.

Comment: Then what is the significance of "Unread Variable"? Do I have to worry tat I've somehow changed the graph that represents my neural net?

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately. It may be that the value returned by `assign` is not actually the same variable as it's modifying, but some temporary variable (with a dummy name) created only to have something to return. The docs say on the `read_value` argument:   "if True, will return _something which evaluates to_ the new value of the variable" (emphasis added). I don't think you have anything to worry about though. `assign` is the standard method to be used for these purposes, and is also used by the built-in optimizers etc.

Answer (score 2):

For a tf.Variable instance, the .assign method has a `read_value` argument that's `True` by default. If `x` is an arbitrary tf.Variable, then for a numpy array `silly` (of the same dimensions as `x`), you can do:

```
x.assign(silly, read_value=False)
```

This won't return anything, but it will change the tf.Variable instance, `x` in place.

For a toy example I adapted from the original post, doing the following:

```
silly = np.zeros([2,2])

x = tf.Variable([[1,0],[0,1]], dtype=tf.float32, name='test')

x.assign(silly, read_value=False)

x
```

resulted in:

```
<tf.Variable 'test:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Obviously not the same exact tensors involved in the original post, but the expected behavior is as desired.

Comment: apparently, the read_value-False is not needed. What I saw was an artifact of my working in an emacs shell, which had echo on. When I repeated in a standard terminal, and typed the variable name, after executing the assign statement, everything was as expected with the Tensorflow variable